# How to get this charSequence volume in Toast?

Tags: java, android

charSequence volume can't be find in the Toast.

```
int volume_level= am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
if (volume_level == 0) {
    CharSequence volume = "Text...";
}
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, volume, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

Note: Disregard this solution:

```
int volume_level= am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
if (volume_level == 0) {
    CharSequence volume = "Text...";
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, volume, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

Comment: You declare a new local variable here: `CharSequence volume` that is only visible inside the `if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ClassName extends AppCompactActivity {

    private String volume;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     int volume_level= am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      if (volume_level == 0) {
         volume = "Text...";
         Toast.makeText(context, volume, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This work, but need to add "private String volume;" in the class.

Comment: in another class? or this class

Comment: In this same class

Answer (score 0):

or
`CharSequence volume = ""; 
if (volume_level == 0) {
    volume = "Text...";
}`

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.